# How to include empty array when filtering an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my item model.

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  category: String,
  occupied: [Number],
  active: { type: Boolean, default: true },
});
```

I want to filter 'occupied' array. So I use aggregate and unwind 'occupied' field.

So I apply match query. And group by _id. 
But if filtered 'occupied' array is empty, the item disappear.

Here is my code

```
Item.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    active: true
  }},
  { $unwind:
    "$occupied",
  },
  { $match: { $and: [
    { occupied: { $gte: 100 }},
    { occupied: { $lt: 200 }}
  ]}},
  { $group : {
    _id: "$_id",
    name: { $first: "$name"},
    category: { $first: "$category"},
    occupied: { $addToSet : "$occupied" }
  }}
], (err, items) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  return res.json({ data: items });
});
```

Here is example data set

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c1bced987fa30b7421a3eb"),
    "name" : "printer1",
    "category" : "printer",
    "occupied" : [ 95, 100, 145, 200 ],
    "active" : true
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59c2dbed992fb91b7421b1ad"),
   "name" : "printer2",
   "category" : "printer",
   "occupied" : [ ],
   "active" : true
}
```

The result above query

```
[
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c1bced987fa30b7421a3eb"),
    "name" : "printer1",
    "category" : "printer",
    "occupied" : [ 100, 145 ],
    "active" : true
  }
]
```

and the result I want

```
[
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c1bced987fa30b7421a3eb"),
    "name" : "printer1",
    "category" : "printer",
    "occupied" : [ 100, 145 ],
    "active" : true
  },
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c2dbed992fb91b7421b1ad"),
    "name" : "printer2",
    "category" : "printer",
    "occupied" : [ ],
    "active" : true
  }
]
```

how could I do this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though it would have been preferred that you found the "pretty print" option for the data samples ( now done pretty ), as far as providing a clear example of the data you have, the result you want and the attempt you have made at achieving it, Many Many people could learn from you how to actually ask a question here. This is exactly how questions should be asked. To the point and complete. Keep it up.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for comment. I'll keep in mind that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest form, you keep it simply by not using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in the first place. Your conditions applied imply that you are looking for the "unique set" of matches to specific values.

For this you instead use  [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), and a "set operator" like [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to reduce the input values to a "set" in the first place:

```
Item.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "active": true } },
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "occupied": { 
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$setUnion": [ "$occupied", []] },
        "as": "o",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            { "$gte": ["$$o", 100 ] },
            { "$lt": ["$$o", 200] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
], (err, items) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  return res.json({ data: items });
});
```

Both have been around since MongoDB v3, so it's pretty common practice to do things this way.

If for some reason you were still using MongoDB 2.6, then you could apply [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) instead:

```
Item.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "active": true } },
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "occupied": { 
      "$setDifference": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$occupied",
          "as": "o",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$and": [
                  { "$gte": ["$$o", 100 ] },
                  { "$lt": ["$$o", 200] }
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$o",
              "else": false
            }
          }
        }},
        [false]
      ]
    }
  }}
], (err, items) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  return res.json({ data: items });
});
```

It's the same "unique set" result as pulling the array apart, filtering the items and putting it back together with [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/). The difference being that its far more efficient, and retains ( or produces ) an empty array without any issues.

Comment: I'm using MongoDB 2.6 now. But I'll update v3 and try your solution. Thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: @125487 As stated in the answer, the second approach is using operators compatible with MongoDB 2.6. I should be noted that if you wanted official support, then [that version is past end of life for support](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy), so upgrading is probably in your best interests.

Comment: I updated MongoDB to v3.4. and your first approach perfectly works. Thanks for comment.